# Reading information from database by controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

The action takes place in the controller asp.net core

// get login person who log on the site

```
var userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; //(works/checked)
```

// takes information about this person from the database

```
var userDetails = _context.Members.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Adlogin == userName);//(works/checked)
```

// compares the login of managers with the login of the manager of the person logged on to the site
// and finds the full name of this manager from the "name" column using his login

```
var nameManager = _context.Members.Where(x => x.Login == userDetails.ManagerLogin).Select(i => new { userNameManager = i.Name}); //(works/checked)
```

// somehow I need to send data via viewdata to the site
// I tried as below but it doesn't work

```
ViewData["Manager"] = nameManager;
```

Error:

> RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.Builders.TextBoxBuilder.Value(string)' has some invalid arguments

//populating the textbox in the view

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
       .Value(ViewBag.Manager)
       .ReadOnly(true)
```

What I want: help with sending / reading information about the manager's name

Comment: How are you populating the textbox in the view?  I think that's where the error is coming from.  Can you show that code please?

Comment: @haldo In view: .Value(ViewData["Manager"]) => CS1503 - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' ||||  In controller: ViewBag.Manager = nameManager => RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.Builders.TextBoxBuilder.Value(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if it helps you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is on this line:

```
var nameManager = _context.Members.Where(x => x.Login == userDetails.ManagerLogin).Select(i => new { userNameManager = i.Name});
```

That will return a collection (even if its just one member).

Use `FirstOrDefault` instead which will return a single `Member`, rather than `Where` which returns a collection.  I'd suggest trying this:

```
var nameManager = _context.Members
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == userDetails.ManagerLogin)?.Name;
```

Now `nameManager` should be a single string (not a collection), it will be the `Name` property of `Member`.

Comment: In element "Members" dont exist deffinition "select" ||||| after First Or Default, already gets fields from the model |||| after FOD I can't use select

Comment: Yes, your right, sorry, I'll update my answer.  Can you try `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == userDetails.ManagerLogin)?.Name` and remove the `Select` completely?